# React-Native AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I didn't understand how to make the AsyncStorage work.
I use react-native-router-flux

Basically I have 3 pages:

**FirstPage**

```
export default class Authentication extends Component {

   render() {
    return (
      ..........


          <TouchableOpacity
            style ={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => Actions.login() }>
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>LOGIN</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style ={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => Actions.signup() }>
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>SIGNUP</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

**Login**

```
login() {
    let ctrl = true;
    ......
    if (ctrl) {

      let formdata = new FormData();
      const identity = {
        AppName: {
          Username: this.state.username,
          Password: this.state.password
        }
      };

      formdata.append("Identity", JSON.stringify(identity));
      fetch(APILINK , {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: formdata
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
          if (responseData.Error) {
            .......
          } else {
            global.utente = new Utente(responseData);
            Actions.homepageutente();
          }
        })
        .catch(err => alert("err:" + err));
    }
  }
```

**Utente**

```
export default class Utente {
  constructor(data) {
    Utente.saveUtenteLoggato(data);
    this._data = data;
    ....
    );
  }
  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }
  //there is a function for the signup there//
  .......

  static async saveUtenteLoggato(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@UtenteLoggato", JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  static async getUtenteLoggato() {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@UtenteLoggato");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }

  static async clearUtenteLoggato() {
    try {
      global.utente = null;
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@UtenteLoggato");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

So in Utente I have created the Asyncstorage function, but I don't understand how I should do when I close the app in backgroun (for example) to maintain the login active. At the moment if I go back in the App I should do another time the Login.
How can I solve it?

**EDIT**
Starting page

```
class Starting extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        loading: true
      }
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    Utente.getUtenteLoggato()
      .then(dataUtenteLoggato => {
        if (dataUtenteLoggato !== null) {
          global.utente = new Utente(JSON.parse(dataUtenteLoggato));
        } else {
          Actions.authentication();
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={style.container}>
        <Spinner visible={this.state.loading} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} />
      </View>
    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement splash screen component and check auth in componentWillMount. As example - get data from AsyncStorage, then perform request to check that user is authenticated and fetch user details. If auth data(e.g. auth token) is absent in storage or server threw auth error(in case when token is invalid or expired), redirect user to login screen, else mark user as authenticated and show main screen.

Comment: I don't have understand how to use splash screen component :/

Comment: @Jack23 Create some component with label "loading" as example and display it when app starts. Until you are accessing AsyncStorage and validating auth data(in componentWillMount of SplashComponent), user see that app is loading. Then you redirect to login screen on fail or to main screen on success

Comment: Ok now I'm understanding xD So in the componetWillMount of the Splash Screen I use the AsyncStorage.getItem("@UtenteLoggato") ?

Comment: @Jack23 yes, exactly

Comment: I edited the code, in which I have created a Starting Page to use like a Splash screen. But I receive only a white page

Comment: @Jack23 dont forget to redirect after `AsyncStorage.getItem` completes

Comment: I have a problem with your implementation. If I use a white page, when I go back with the button (in the app or the phone button) I returned in the white page :/

Comment: @Jack23 Use `Actions.main({type: 'reset'})`(main - your component's router key) to prevent user back to splash screen